# Print web form - yii framework

Tags: forms, frameworks, printing, yii

I've a web page, done with the Yii Framework. On it I have several pages, some with webforms that present data from the database.

When I try to print, it prints the entire webpage, but I don't want that. I want to print only the form fields, after pressing a button.

I know several website do this, they allow it to print directly or create a pdf.

What's the best way to do this? Via php code, html code, css?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of extensions that might help you: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/printout/ and http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mprint/. The latter uses this script http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm.